# Compare two arrays of points

Tags: algorithm, math, pseudocode

I'm trying to find a way to find similarities in two arrays of different points. I drew circles around points that have similar patterns and I would like to do some kind of auto comparison in intervals of let's say 100 points and tell what coefficient of similarity is for that interval. As you can see it might not be perfectly aligned also so point-to-point comparison would not be a good solution also (I suppose). Patterns that are slightly misaligned could also mean that they are matching the pattern (but obviously with a smaller coefficient)

What similarity could mean (1 coefficient is a perfect match, 0 or less - is not a match at all):

1. Points 640 to 660 - Very similar (coefficient is ~0.8)
2. Points 670 to 690 - Quite similar (coefficient is ~0.5-~0.6)
3. Points 720 to 780 - Let's say quite similar (coefficient is ~0.5-~0.6)
4. Points 790 to 810 - Perfectly similar (coefficient is 1)

Coefficient is just my thoughts of how a final calculated result of comparing function could look like with given data.

I read many posts on SO but it didn't seem to solve my problem. I would appreciate your help a lot. Thank you

P.S. Perfect answer would be the one that provides pseudo code for function which could accept two data arrays as arguments (intervals of data) and return coefficient of similarity.

[image: Points to compare]

[Click here to see original size of image](http://grab.by/p8R8)

Comment: Could you clarify about - what type of data your `point` is? And what it represents? (That graphics that you've provided are too small to see that)

Comment: I think you're looking for some measure(s) of *correlation* or *cross-correlation*.  Too complicated for me to attempt an explanation or offer pseudo-code *ab initio*.  Suggest you check the topics out (on Wikipedia perhaps) and return with a sharpened question.

Comment: @Eugene point is just an integer number: arrayA = [0,1,2,0] and arrayB = [0,1,2,0] would be a perfect match. But arrayA = [0,1,2,0] and arrayB = [0,0,1,2] would be a very similar match but would require alignment. And arrayA = [0,1,2,0] with arrayB = [0,2,3,0] would mean also very similar or quite similar match because the patterns are similar.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a good measure of similarity in data. It would fit better on http://math.stackexchange.org or http://stats.stackexchange.org

Comment: @Chowlett I'm convinced that if you were active on [math.se] you wouldn't think it fits there. I'm not really sure about [stats.se]. This question doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem, which is the main reason it doesn't fit here.

Comment: What I'm expecting from the answers is a working pseudo-code that I could try and see if it works. I suppose if I asked on math or stats portal I would get a bunch of theory or algorithms that I would not know what to do. That's why I asked here.
P.S. seeing that my question got a few up votes I believe it might be relevant to others too.

Comment: Just because a few users, who likely don't know what's appropriate for [so], upvoted your question doesn't mean that your question conforms to the [so] rules. Allowing anything that's relevant to others but doesn't conform to the rules generally quickly severely reduces the quality of any site (selective allowing is a different story).

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question now.  It's not just that the question is off-topic as other commentators have noted, it's more that the answers offend me (other than those that pick up on my earlier comment).  They offend me because they are programmer hacks at a problem which is extensively studied and for which there are very good published algorithms and, I expect, open-source codes to study or implement. They do not show any awareness of that background to the question.

Comment: Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) is designed to measure time series similarities. The main challenge would be to know which segments to compare against if you expect similar patterns anywhere. In that case, a sliding-window approach plus DTW would give you a brute force (and slow) solution to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

i think HighPerformanceMarks's suggestion is the standard way of doing the job.

a computationally lightweight alternative measure might be a dot product.

- split both arrays into the same predefined index intervals.
- consider the array elements in each intervals as vector coordinates in high-dimensional space.
- compute the dot product of both vectors.

the dot product will not be negative. if the two vectors are perpendicular in their vector space, the dot product will be 0 (in fact that's how 'perpendicular' is usually defined in higher dimensions), and it will attain its maximum for identical vectors.

if you accept the geometric notion of perpendicularity as a (dis)similarity measure, here you go.

caveat:
this is an ad hoc heuristic chosen for computational efficiency. i cannot tell you about  mathematical/statistical properties of the process and separation properties - if you need rigorous analysis, however, you'll probably fare better with correlation theory anyway and should perhaps forward your question to [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I suppose that cross-correlation is the term that I was looking for though I can not accept the answer of HighPerformanceMarks because it is only a comment. Also thank you I will try your aproach

Answer (score 0):

I also think High Performance Mark has basically given you the answer (cross-correlation).  In my opinion, most of the other answers are only giving you half of what you need (i.e., dot product plus compare against some threshold).  However, this won't consider a signal to be similar to a shifted version of itself.  You'll want to compute this dot product N + M - 1 times, where N, M are the sizes of the arrays.  For each iteration, compute the dot product between array 1 and a shifted version of array 2.  The amount you shift array 2 increases by one each iteration.  You can think of array 2 as a window you are passing over array 1.  You'll want to start the loop with the last element of array 2 only overlapping the first element in array 1.

This loop will generate numbers for different amounts of shift, and what you do with that number is up to you.  Maybe you compare it (or the absolute value of it) against a threshold that you define to consider two signals "similar".

Lastly, in many contexts, a signal is considered similar to a scaled (in the amplitude sense, not time-scaling) version of itself, so there must be a normalization step prior to computing the cross-correlation.  This is usually done by scaling the elements of the array so that the dot product with itself equals 1.  Just be careful to ensure this makes sense for your application numerically, i.e., integers don't scale very well to values between 0 and 1 :-)

Answer (score -1):

My Attempt:

```
Total_sum=0
1. For each index i in the range (m,n)
2.     sum=0
3.     k=Array1[i]*Array2[i]; t1=magnitude(Array1[i]); t2=magnitude(Array2[i]);
4.     k=k/(t1*t2)
5.     sum=sum+k
6. Total_sum=Total_sum+sum
Coefficient=Total_sum/(m-n)
```

If all values are equal, then sum would return 1 in each case and total_sum would return (m-n)*(1). Hence, when the same is divided by (m-n) we get the value as 1. If the graphs are exact opposites, we get -1 and for other variations a value between -1 and 1 is returned. 
This is not so efficient when the y range or the x range is huge. But, I just wanted to give you an idea.

Another option would be to perform an extensive xnor.

```
1. For each index i in the range (m,n)
2.     sum=1
3.     k=Array1[i] xnor Array2[i]; 
4.     k=k/((pow(2,number_of_bits))-1) //This will scale k down to a value between 0 and 1
5.     sum=(sum+k)/2

Coefficient=sum
```

Is this helpful ?

Comment: Note that if you have a vector `v` of huge size, comparing `v || 0` and `0 || v` will give a terrible result, though they are very similar. Some alignment must be used.

Comment: Hmm.. yeah. A more elegant solution might be needed here.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a distance metric for two vectors A and B of length N containing numbers in the interval [-1, 1] e.g. as

```
 sum = 0
 for i in 0 to 99:
   d = (A[i] - B[i])^2  // this is in range 0 .. 4
 sum = (sum / 4) / N // now in range 0 .. 1
```

This now returns distance 1 for vectors that are completely opposite (one is all 1, another all -1), and 0 for identical vectors.

You can translate this into your coefficient by

```
 coeff = 1 - sum
```

However, this is a crude approach because it does not take into account the fact that there could be horizontal distortion or shift between the signals you want to compare, so let's look at some approaches for coping with that.

You can *sort* both your arrays (e.g. in ascending order) and then calculate the distance / coefficient. This returns more similarity than the original metric, and is agnostic towards permutations / shifts of the signal.

You can also calculate the differentials and calculate distance / coefficient for those, and then you can do that sorted also. Using differentials has the benefit that it eliminates vertical shifts. Sorted differentials eliminate horizontal shift but still recognize different shapes better than sorted original data points.

You can then e.g. average the different coefficients. Here more complete code. The routine below calculates coefficient for arrays A and B of given size, and takes d many differentials (recursively) first. If sorted is true, the final (differentiated) array is sorted.

```
procedure calc(A, B, size, d, sorted):
  if (d > 0):
     A' = new array[size - 1]
     B' = new array[size - 1]
     for i in 0 to size - 2:
        A'[i] = (A[i + 1] - A[i]) / 2   // keep in range -1..1 by dividing by 2
        B'[i] = (B[i + 1] - B[i]) / 2
     return calc(A', B', size - 1, d - 1, sorted)
  else:
     if (sorted):
       A = sort(A)
       B = sort(B)
     sum = 0
     for i in 0 to size - 1:
       sum = sum + (A[i] - B[i]) * (A[i] - B[i])
     sum = (sum / 4) / size
     return 1 - sum // return the coefficient

procedure similarity(A, B, size):
  sum a = 0
  a = a + calc(A, B, size, 0, false)
  a = a + calc(A, B, size, 0, true)
  a = a + calc(A, B, size, 1, false)
  a = a + calc(A, B, size, 1, true)
  return a / 4 // take average
```

For something completely different, you could also run Fourier transform using FFT and then take a distance metric on the returning spectra.

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to give some ideas... if you took series 0000000011111111 and 0101010101010101 their differentials would be 0000000010000000 and 1X1X1X1X1X1X1X1X X denoting -1, and the differential arrays would be distinct even after sorting. 'similarity' procedure could have weights that could be tuned according to needs